# Python: extract tuples with max/min n'th element from array of tuples

Tags: python

In Python I have some data that looks like this:

```
A = [
(-9, [(2, 3), (5, 2), (3,1)]), 
(-8, [(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 6)]), 
(-8, [(0, 0), (5, 0), (1, 6)]),
(-9, [(2, 3), (4, 2), (4, 5)]), 
]
```

What is the most pythonic way to extract the element or elements that have the maximum value in the first entry? Changing the data structure is not an option.

In this example, the goal is to return the two middle tuples.

Cheers!

Comment: `max(A, key=lambda x: x[0])` will retrieve _one_ of the elements. In general, the `key=` parameter in functions like `max()` or `sorted()`, etc, can be used for more complex comparisons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
max_value = max(x[0] for x in A)
print [x for x in A if x[0] == max_value]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LPCyW)

Comment: Wouldn't that execute `max()` every time?

Comment: @RikPoggi: I think you are correct. Probably not an serious issue with the example data, but it would be an issue if the list contains thousands of items. I've updated the code so that the maximum is calculated only once.